# How to count the number of elements in one array (with duplicates) that match with elements of another array in SQL(Presto)?

Tags: sql, arrays, presto, array-intersect

I have two arrays X,Y. `X=[a,b,c]` and `Y=[a,a,b,b,b,c,d,d,e,e,e]`. I want to write a query that will return the number of elements in Y that match the elements in X (with duplicates). in this case the out put should be `[a,a,b,b,b,c]` and I need the length of this array which is 6. I know array_intersect will return with no duplicates.

```
SELECT array_intersect([a,b,c],[a,a,b,b,b,c,d,d,e,e,e])
```

the result is

```
[a,b,c]
```

but my desired output is

```
[a,a,b,b,b,c]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with `filter` and `contains`:

```sql
SELECT filter(array['a','a','b','b','b','c','d','d'], el -> contains(array['a','b','c'], el))
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [a, a, b, b, b, c] |